# Android - Error inflating class fragment (trying to get google maps api v2 to work)

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I've searched everywhere for a solution to this error but I can't seem to find a solution that works for me.  Every time I run the program it crashes, the problem seems to be in the fragment tag in the XML file.

Many thanks if you can take a look at the code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package jondadi.atm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
  }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="jondadi.atm"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
   android:name="jondadi.atm.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
   android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
   android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
   android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="jondadi.atm.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="jondadi.atm.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyD0L90SyrdZRdn3v4aQe05HUQJi1viLiyA" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

The Logcat error(The log is much much longer, let me know if you want it all):

```
11-06 02:29:02.165: E/AndroidRuntime(8238): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 02:29:02.165: E/AndroidRuntime(8238): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jondadi.atm/jondadi.atm.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
11-06 02:29:02.165: E/AndroidRuntime(8238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)

11-06 02:29:02.165: E/AndroidRuntime(8238): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
11-06 02:29:02.165: E/AndroidRuntime(8238): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

within the application element. This will solve:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about your code, but you can try extending **Activity** instead of **FragmentActivity** in your `MainActivity`.

Also, i haven't ever used:

```
<permission
android:name="jondadi.atm.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

i dont know what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I used to have the class extent Activity but that gave me the same error.

Comment: can you please post the full stacktrace for my reference